# Resolving Display Issues with Radeon HD 4850 on iMac27 Mid-2010 in Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: graphics, radeon

Hello Ask Ubuntu Community,

I am facing a display issue on my iMac27 (mid-2010 model, iMac11,3) with a Radeon RV770/M98L (Mobility Radeon HD 4850) graphics card after installing Ubuntu 22.04.3. Below is the detailed description of my problem and the troubleshooting steps I have taken:

Issue Description:

Booting without nomodeset parameters results in a black screen on the built-in display.
When an external monitor is connected, it functions correctly, but the built-in screen shows white lines on a black background.
If I add nomodeset to the GRUB parameters, everything works fine but no used graphic card.
However, adding acpi=off in GRUB makes the built-in display work, but then USB controllers stop functioning.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Ensured xserver-xorg-video-radeon driver is installed and up to date.

Conducted system updates and upgrades.
System Specifications:

iMac Model: iMac27, Mid-2010 (iMac11,3)
Graphics Card: Radeon RV770/M98L (Mobility Radeon HD 4850)
Ubuntu Version: 22.04.3
I am seeking assistance to:

**How to resolve the black screen issue on the built-in display without compromising USB functionality?**
Find the best configuration for my Radeon HD 4850 under Ubuntu 22.04.3.
Any advice, troubleshooting tips, or insights into resolving these issues would be immensely appreciated. I can provide further details if needed.

Thank you for your time and help!